# jqplot- Dynamically setting renderer

Tags: drupal, jqplot

I'm working on a drupal module using jqplot library to display charts using [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. Here I'm dynamically setting renderer. Charts module set all the details as json string to data-* attribute of the chart div, at runtime which is decoded and passed to jqplot function. Here renderer is set up dynamically and it giving error. **TypeError: this.renderer.init is undefined**

If I set renderer manually it works perfectly, what is the correct way to set up renderer dynamically?

Codes can be found [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jqPlot/tree/charts_jqplot).